# What can my ISP see in their log files if I use Google DNS?

Tags: dns, logging

For example, if I use my ISP DNS and open this page they will see:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

It would show up in their logs for sure.

But if I use Google DNS, then what EXACTLY can they see?

Do they log this as:

http://204.93.58.117/questions/ask

or just:

http://204.93.58.117/

I'm asking this because my government seems to monitor too much. I know about VPN
but I don't use VPN all the time. I simply want to know what can ISP log when I'm
not using VPN, only Google public DNS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are URLs viewed during HTTPS transactions to one or more websites from a single IP distinguishable?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4388/are-urls-viewed-during-https-transactions-to-one-or-more-websites-from-a-single)

Comment: No it is not duplicate

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by "their log files"? It's too broad. Short answer: They can log everything. They can ready everything that's not well encrypted. For example, it could be logging your computer/router's MAC, or logging routed traffic both to one of Google's DNS servers (to resolve the FQDN) and to 204.93.58.117 or to Tor nodes, or the DNS query itself, or TCP flags, or SSL / TLS negotiations, or logging the URL and cookies in the HTTP layer of the subsequent page request, or the PNG image or XML in the request body, or... you get the picture. But many logs reduce performance.

Answer (score 11):

**Short answer:** they are only able to log the hosts you visit (e.g. security.stackexchange.com, google.com, etc) and not the full address (e.g. `https://stackexchange.com/login`). If you access unencrypted webpages (`http` instead of `https`), they are able to see everything. ISP are not known to log unencrypted webpages en masse, but I wouldn't not be surprised if the NSA or china logs this kind of meta information.

**Long answer:**
Since DNS traffic is not encrypted, your ISP could see every host you visit (it does not matter if you use Google's DNS or theirs). If you visit `https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/ask` (note the `s` after http), your ISP will see that you visited `security.stackexchange.com` and that you used HTTPS. If you use HTTP, the will see everything (the content of the webpage, url, and sometimes even cookies. Note that `security.stackexchange.com` will always redirect you to their HTTPS version. This means your ISP will only see that you were redirected to the encrypted version. If you are not on the https version, you're being MITM'd. You should then use a VPN).

If you request `http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/ask` (as you have originally asked), your ISP will also be able to tell that you requested the very page since it is not encrypted. It does not matter that Stack Exchange is redirecting you to the encrypted version because the you have already access the unencrypted version once. Make sure you always use `https` when possible.

If you access google via `216.58.192.110` (one of their IPs), your ISP will still be able to see that you visited `216.58.192.110`. Since your ISP is also probably running a DNS server, they could also check where `216.58.192.110` resolved to (which will probably return google). They could also check that by hand, but this would take more time.

The only way to protect you from these attacks is if you use a VPN. Note that by using a VPN you simply shift the trust to someone else. If you use a public VPN, there are many more parties who can monitor your traffic: the VPN provider (their server might log everything you do), the server host, and the government the server is located in.

Comment: ISP uses DNS servers to log visited pages right? If I use third party DNS like Google Open DNS then they cant? Right? I know they can track anything if they really want to but what usually happens if you use third party DNS? I gues they dont have logs about visited pages...

Comment: @Marko No, ISPs don't use DNS to log visited pages. All DNS can log is what *domains* you're talking to, but that's already visible to the ISP (even with TLS, the domain is generally sent unencrypted). DNS is not capable of logging visited URLs, because it has nothing to do with URLs (just domain names, but not the protocol or the path).

Comment: @Marko I added a short answer, which hopefully clarifies my explanation.

Comment: @cpast Matt3o Thanks you for you answers.This is my real question...I stopped using Facebook some times ago as accused of sending insults to some people...I live in a country which has bad cooperation with Facebook... I did not do that, I just didn't. Few days ago I used search engine to find FB page of a woman who accused me. When I opened that page it sent 503 error code... so it should be only visible that I opened fb because it is HTTPS but it returned HTTP error page (error code 503)because server was down.In address bar was full address, it said http instead HTTPS with full adress of tha

Comment: @cpast If you open page like httpsfacebook.com/somepage and you get this in your adress bar httpsfacebook.com/somepage and 503 error message for that page is full URL recorded by ISP? Thanks

Comment: If the address bar said http, your ISP could save it although I doubt that will be checked unless the woman is suing you. If you are looking for an easy way to access pages in a more secure way, use https://hide.me just make sure you use HTTPS and the site has a valid certificate. They offer a free proxy and a free VPN (up to 300mbs). Disclaimer: I'm not affiliated with that company. I only use it and I'm a happy customer).

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://security.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://security.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.

Comment: @Matt3o Even if I used Google public DNS servers?

Comment: @Marko yes. It does not matter because it is not encrypted. Your ISP will aways know what ip addresses you have accessed unless you use a VPN. Also remember that you access Facebook unknowingly every time a site uses a like button (because our browser access Facebook in order to load the button). If you found my answer helpful, could you please upvote and accept it.

Comment: @Matt3o Thanks. I don't care if they know which IP adress I visited, in this case facebook, I only care if they know full url about that page since I used Google Public DNS. I cant upvote because I don't have credits of some kind.So it is ok for me that isp knows I have visited fb, not ok they know full url. I promise to come back and upvote

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: Then who can see the full url? No one?

Comment: @JavaTechnical, assuming you have not been MITM'ed, only your computer and the webserver you visited (although your browser might sync your history to some kind of cloud service).

Comment: If you're on a corporate network or cafe hotspot, by the way, MiTM (aka SSL inspection) is pretty standard practice, so their network admins will have seen the URL, too, as long as they have it enabled. SSL inspection is common in network security gear like Juniper and Fortinet: https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos15.1x49/topics/concept/security-utm-enhanced-web-filtering-functionality-understanding.html

Answer (score 2):

An ISP is literally an "internet provider". As such they provide you the wires and equipment to access the global scaled network.

Since they are in between you and the rest of the world, you have to assume that anything not encrypted is potentially logged by your ISP. Even if you use Google DNS, the DNS request will be send from your computer, to your modem, to an equipment of your ISP, then to Google DNS.

DNS is not commonly encrypted and contains the name of the site you ask for resolution, thus they can log it. Furthermore, IPs can be passed through a reverse DNS which will return the name the IP is associated with (actually the main name).

Whether they do log DNS request or not is not in the scope of the site.

After your DNS request, your computer has to access the website. In the same way, if the session is not encrypted, it can be logged.

As a matter of fact, even encrypted traffic can be logged, but it can't be read (unless you can break the crypto).

Answer (score 1):

Lookup DNS over HTTPS (DoH) and DNS over TLS (DoT). You can encrypt your DNS traffic. My Asus Router supports DoT features. Newer business routers are also getting on board.

My setup is simple and works well. I use DoT to Cloudflare's family DNS servers 1.1.1.3 and 1.0.0.3 on the router. My main workstation/gaming rig runs Windows 11 and it supports DoH out of the box and I point it to 1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1 over DoH.