# Can my company see my network traffic if their certificate doesn't appear in the web browser?

Tags: certificates, privacy, man-in-the-middle, certificate-authority

I have a work-issued Mac, when I go to keychain access right now these are the following certificates:

1. AddTrust External CA Root (Root certificate authority)
2. COMODO RSA Certification Authority (Root certificate authority)
3. COMODO RSA Certification Authority (Intermediate certificate authority)
4. COMODO RSA Organization Validation Secure Server CA (Intermediate certificate authority)
5. ise-auth.[company name].com (Issued by COMODO RSA Organization Validation Secure Server CA)
6. My account name (Issued by [some certificate from my company])

So I see there is a certificate on my computer from my company. However, when I access websites and click the padlock on the browser I don't see my company's certificate. For example, with google.com the certificate chain I see is GlobalSign -> Google Internet Authority G3 -> google.com. Does this mean my traffic is encrypted if I'm on their wifi? Or can they still see traffic?

Comment: Note that if it's their computer, there are other ways they could record your data besides an interception proxy. It's also a bit unclear to me what the function of #5 is and if it's even a risk in this case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can my employer see what I do on the internet when I am connected to the company network?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/142803), [Can my company see what HTTPS sites I went to?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2914).

Comment: From the name of the #5, I would suggest that there is a Cisco ISE doing network access control (NAC). BTW: this does not seem like a duplicate question to me.

Comment: No other trusted roots, how would the browser work?